# Chaining custom systemd services

Tags: systemd

I have timer `A` that every few hours runs a script that runs service `B`(script with `systemctl start` in it). Then I would like to run service `C` after `B` is finished.

Here is my service `C`:

```
[Unit]
Description=lorem ipsum
Requires=B.service
After=B.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=echo
```

`B` is also Type=oneshot.

Problem: after I invoke `systemctl start B.service` the `C` is not automatically launched. I doesn't have [Install] section because I don't want them to start on boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your got it backwards. `After` does not specify that service `C`needs to be started, see  [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) for more information.

You want something like that as your configuration for service `B`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Your service C
Requires=C.service
Before=C.service
...
```

Comment: Yeah, I've figured that out, but it's not he best soultion. I more like concept of 'observable' so that B doesnt have to know about every other service that needs to be triggered after it.

Comment: It is probabably the best solution available. I can not find any directive that would allow this configuration without reconfiguration of service B