# Systemd: how to start a service after another, started by timer, finishes?

Tags: systemd, debian-stretch

## The goal

On Debian Stretch, we want to download any updates and install them immediately because we monitor the number of pending upgrades and currently get notifications for routine conditions.

## Standard stretch

Standard stretch downloads updates and installs them using:

- apt-daily.service
- apt-daily.timer
- apt-daily-upgrade.service
- apt-daily-upgrade.timer

The timers run independently at random daily times so there can be almost 24 hours between download and installation.

## Research and attempts

### apt-daily-upgrade.service modification

Based on https://superuser.com/questions/1250874/trigger-another-systemd-unit-to-start-before-timer-unit-starts, I disabled apt-daily-upgrade.timer and modified apt-daily-upgrade.service, adding "Wants=apt-daily.service"

Did run systemctl daemon-reload after the change.

24+ hours later /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log did not show unattended-upgrades had been run.

### apt-daily.service modification

Based on [Chaining custom systemd services](https://serverfault.com/questions/771707/chaining-custom-systemd-services), I understood apt-daily.service needs to be configured to start apt-daily-upgrade.service rather than apt-daily-upgrade.service being configured to start after apt-daily.service.

Backed out the apt-daily-upgrade.service modification and created /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.service with addition "Before=apt-daily-upgrade.service":

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt download activities
Documentation=man:apt(8)
ConditionACPower=true
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Before=apt-daily-upgrade.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
```

Did run systemctl daemon-reload after the change.

24+ hours later /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log did not show unattended-upgrades had been run.

The systemd journal showed "Daily apt download activities" messages, believed to show that apt-daily.service had been run:

```
# journalctl | grep 'apt download activities'
Apr 08 16:10:05 web2.iciti.av systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Apr 08 16:10:08 web2.iciti.av systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
...
```

## Conclusion

How can we effect our goal, ideally within the systemd framework?

Comment: before/after are for adding dependencies. I think it does not add a new service in the execution list. Can you try to Want/Require the apt-daily-upgrade.service?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user228505, that worked.

/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.service was changed to

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt download activities
Documentation=man:apt(8)
ConditionACPower=true
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Before=apt-daily-upgrade.service
Wants=apt-daily-upgrade.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
```

We needed that to run apt-daily-upgrade.service after apt-daily.service had finished (to download all packages before running unattended upgrades).

Adding APT::Periodic::Verbose "3" to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/02periodic showed it was doing what we wanted.

Apparently the systemd message "Started Daily apt download activities" means "Finished Daily apt download activities" because /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily does not return until it has finished (unlike most service commands which return when they daemonize).